# How to shift property values of objects in arrays without copying all values first?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

For example, suppose I have array:

```
let students=[
    {"name":"a","uid":"001"},
    {"name":"b","uid":"002"},
    {"name":"c","uid":"003"}
];
```

I want to shift the value of uid, expected result:

```
let students=[
    {"name":"a","uid":"002"},
    {"name":"b","uid":"003"},
    {"name":"c","uid":"001"}
];
```

How can I do it without copying all uid into a new array first? I tried:

```js
let students=[
        {"name":"a","uid":"001"},
        {"name":"b","uid":"002"},
        {"name":"c","uid":"003"}
    ];
let temp=students[0].uid;
for(let i=0;i<students.length;i++){
  students[(i+1)%students.length].uid=temp;
  temp=students[i].uid;
}

for(let s of students){
  console.log(s.name+':'+s.uid+',');
}
```

but it is not working as I expected.

Comment: please share the condition on which the values will be shifted

Comment: What exactly is the restriction you mention here? `without copying all uid into a new array first?` Do you mean that no new variables can be created in the process?

Comment: I really didn't understand the way you wanted to shift ? was it shift or sort ? or something else, I couldn't grab the change pattern

Comment: @brk It's just shifting all `uid`s up one item in the array (plus wrap-around)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let students=[
        {"name":"a","uid":"001"},
        {"name":"b","uid":"002"},
        {"name":"c","uid":"003"}
    ];

let temp = students[0].uid
for(let i=0;i<students.length;i++){
  let temp2 = students[(i+1)%students.length].uid
  students[(i+1)%students.length].uid=temp;
  temp = temp2
}

for(let s of students){
  console.log(s.name+':'+s.uid+',');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it. You need to copy only the first one. I'm providing only pseudo code since we don't do homework in Stack Overflow:

```
first_uuid = students[0].uuid
for loop from students[0] to students[one before last]
     student[i].uuid = student[i+i].uuid
student[last] = first_uuid
```

In your code you don't need to mess with modulus or touch `temp`.